# How can I make a pretzel shape using Bézier curves?

Tags: graphics3d, splines, homework

I am trying to make a pretzel shape,but I cannot seem to get the loops even.

Eventually, I need to make the pretzel shape loop in 3D so I need to nail the 2D concept first. Here's what I have so far.

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 4, 0}, {3, 2, 0}};
curve = Graphics3D[BSplineCurve[points, SplineClosed -> True]];
Graphics3D[{BSplineCurve[pts, SplineClosed -> True], Green, Line[pts],
   Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to proceed ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnotCurve.html

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pretzel+curve

Comment: I have to use a Bezier curve.. it's for homework.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you make your control polygon have three-fold symmetry.

Comment: Try playing around with something like Inkscape or Illustrator to get a handle on how bezier curve work (pun fully intended).  Or try out [this game](http://bezier.method.ac/).

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `LocatorPane` to edit the control points (at least in 2 dimensions) and see the curve change in real time:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}];

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
 Dynamic[Graphics[
   {
    BSplineCurve[pts],
    Dotted, Line[pts]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]]
```

[image]

If you play around with the points a little, getting a pretzel shouldn't be too difficult.