# Visualize a pretzel using a closed cubic B-spline and Tube

Tags: graphics, splines

I want to visualize a 3D nonplanar pretzel using a closed cubic B-spline displayed with `Tube`.

I'm just absolutely lost on the whole thing. The closest pretzel shape I've been able to make was using this:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Sin[x/2])*Cos[x], (3 + Sin[x/2])*Sin[x], 2 Cos[x/2]}, 
    {x, 0, 15}] 
  /. 
    Line -> (Tube[#, 0.4] &), 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

But that's not using a B-spline, and I can't seem to find any documentation on creating 3D objects with a B-spline and `Tube`.

Comment: In the [documentation of `Tube`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) you find how to use `Tube` and `BSpline` together: `Graphics3D[
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{1, 1, -1}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, -1}, {3, 4, 1}}]]]`

Comment: Related: [How can I make a pretzel shape using Bézier curves?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76973/131)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) and [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76973/131) (for the number of points needed):

```
Graphics3D[
 Tube[BSplineCurve[{{-1, 0, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {0, -2, 1}, {-3, 2, 1}, {1,
      0, 1}}], 0.05]]
```

[image]

Play with the 5 points until you are satisfied.

Comment: awesome, thanks a bunch